# Python itertools.product build sum and add to new list

Tags: python

Input from 100 Percent to 1 Percent in 1% steps

I have 3 Different ingredients and they can be in any mixture but the sum needs to be 100%.

What I tried so far is this:

```
inputlist = linspace(100, 1, 100) 
outputlist = list(itertools.product(inputlist, repeat = 3))
```

this gives me a new list that looks like this:

```
(100, 100, 100), (100, 100, 99), (100, 100, 98), ......, (1, 1, 1)
```

in the next step I calculate each () and check if the sum is 100.

now I want to add the results to a new list

```
newoutput = (98, 1, 1), (50, 20, 30)....
```

I don't know what the best way is to create that list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) and list comprehension to filter the combinations which have the total as 100

```
result = [i for i in itertools.product(inputlist, repeat = 3) if sum(i) == 100]
```

Actually, if you don't want to use the same number again, you have to use `itertools.combinations`

```
result = [i for i in itertools.combinations(inputlist, r = 3) if sum(i) == 100]
```

For the sample runs

```
data = range(100)
from itertools import product, combinations
result = [i for i in product(data, repeat = 3) if sum(i) == 100]
print(len(result))   # 5148
result = [i for i in combinations(data, r = 3) if sum(i) == 100]
print(len(result))   # 833
```